# SQL*Plus pass path to script file from command line

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

What I'd like to do is parameterize the SPOOL path "C:\" so that in command line I can pass a path.

Sample script MyFile.sql:

```
SPOOL "C:\Temp\File.csv"  --How do I parameterize this?
SELECT Column FROM Table
SPOOL OFF
```

CommandLine: 
SQL> @C\MyFile.sql --Would like to pass in a path here.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could do:

```
SPOOL &1
SELECT...
SPOOL OFF

SQL> @C\MyFile.sql C:\Temp\File.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way i can think of would be to call sqlplus from a .bat file that takes as input the parameter, writes out a primary SQL script which contains the spool + the parameter and then calls your actual script.

You would get an extra @secondary_script_name.sql at the beginning of output though.